# Login after successful signup Ember-Simple-Auth

Tags: javascript, authentication, ember.js, ember-app-kit

I have set up a auto-authenticate for user after signup:

app/libs/auto-authenticate.js

```
export default Ember.SimpleAuth.Authenticators.OAuth2.extend({                  
   authenticate: function(credentials) {                                                        
     if(!Ember.isEmpty(credentials.access_token)) {                               
       return Ember.RSVP.resolve(credentials);                                                  
     } else {                                                                                   
       return this._super(credentials);                                                         
     }                                                                                          
   }                                                                                            
});
```

app/app.js

```
import AutoAuthenticate from 'appkit/libs/auto-authenticate';
App.initializer({                                                                              
    name: 'auto',                                                                                
    initialize: function(container, application) {                                               
      container.register('app:authenticators:custom', AutoAuthenticator);         
      Ember.SimpleAuth.setup(container, application);                                            
    }                                                                             
 });
```

app/controllers/register.js

```
  export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    firstname: '',                                                                
    lastname: '',                                                                                
    username: '',                                                                                
    password: '',                                                                                                                                                                             
    actions: {                                                                                   
      registerUser: function(){                                                                  
        var self = this;                                                                         
        var user = this.store.createRecord('user', {                                             
          first_name: this.get('firstname'),                                       
          last_name: this.get('lastname'),                                                       
          username: this.get('username')                                                         
        });
        user.set('typedPass', this.get('password'));                                             
        user.save().then(function(){                                                             
          //How can I login this user using ember-simple-auth ?? 
        });                                                                       
      }                                                                                          
    }                                                                                            
 });
```

I have separate Login for users that will provide their username and password.

What I want to do is , when a new user signs up in the website I want that user to logged in directly without going to the login page and providing its username/password ? As I am getting the username and password from the registration process, I dont want the user to go to another route and then login . How to call the custom authenticator to authenticate the current signed up user with its login credentials??

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best solution would probably to just reuse the username and password properties you already have in the registration controller:

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  firstname: '',                                                                
  lastname: '',                                                                                
  username: '',                                                                                
  password: '',                                                                                                                                                                             
  actions: {                                                                                   
    registerUser: function(){                                                                  
      var self = this;                                                                         
      var user = this.store.createRecord('user', {                                             
        first_name: this.get('firstname'),                                       
        last_name: this.get('lastname'),                                                       
        username: this.get('username')                                                         
      });
      user.set('typedPass', this.get('password'));                                             
      user.save().then(function() {                                                             
        //this is basically what happens when you trigger the LoginControllerMixin's "authenticate" action
        this.get('session').authenticate('app:authenticators:custom', {
          identification: this.get('username'),
          password: this.get('password')
        });
      });                                                                       
    }                                                                                          
  }
```

});

Comment: Some parts I have to change like this.get('session').authenticate('app:authenticators:custom', {
          identification: this.get('username'),
          password: this.get('password')
        });
to::
self.get('session').authenticate('app:authenticators:custom', {
          identification: self.get('username'),
          password: self.get('password')
        });

Comment: And if I refresh I am getting this errorUncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'restore' of undefined  , line 1136 this.container.lookup(authenticatorFactory).restore(restoredContent).then(function(content) {

Comment: that error indicates that Ember.SimpleAuth persisted an authenticator factory that it doesn't get an authenticator instance for from the container. Are you maybe registering the authenticator incorrectly?

Comment: what i have implemented is here only except the OAuth2 setup for the Login that I am using for normal login .

Comment: :: this is the whole code that I have till now, https://gist.github.com/shadow-fox/8f017c33a5bb3000af59

Comment: One more issue is that with simple login also, I am getting this error msg : Cannot re-register: `ember-simple-auth:authenticators:oauth2`, as it has already been looked up. https://gist.github.com/shadow-fox/8f017c33a5bb3000af59#file-app-js-L42

Comment: hm, not sure why that's being re-registered there; anyway as you're using he default OAuth2 authenticator anyway you don't need container.register('app:authenticators:custom', AutoAuthenticator);

Also you should change this:

    self.get('session').authenticate('app:authenticators:custom', {
      identification: self.get('username'),
      password: self.get('password')
    });

to this:

    self.get('session').authenticate('ember-simple-auth:authenticators:oauth2', {
      identification: self.get('username'),
      password: self.get('password')
    });

Comment: I removed the AutoAuthenticator from the code and also commented out the Ember.SimpleAuth.setup(container, application) , and applied what you said, its working with the normal login and after sign up, But what if I want to add Facebook authenticate or twitter , then only it will show that it cant re-register

Comment: Oh, I see what the problem is - you're running Ember.SimpleAuth.setup more than once. That doesn't work. You only run it once. Of course you can register more than one authenticator and then choose one when you authenticate the session.

Comment: So that means, I will restore the autoauthenticate and remove the Ember.SimpleAuth.setup(container, application) line ?? And it will good to go ?

Comment: I have a working example with auto-login based upon your discussion here: https://github.com/digitalplaywright/eak-simple-auth

Answer (score 1):

We use devise and had this same issue. I'm not entirely happy with this solution but we returned the devise auth token in the response to `user.save()` and called `session#setup` directly as follows:

```
user.save().then(function(user) {
    var secure = self.session.get('secure');
    secure.token = user.get('deviseAuthToken');
    secure.email = user.get('email');
    self.session.setup('simple-auth-authenticator:devise', secure, true);
}
```

With the new ember-simple-auth 1.0 addon we moved this code into a custom authenticator:

```
//app/authenticators/registration.js

import Ember from 'ember';
import DeviseAuthenticator from 'ember-simple-auth/authenticators/devise';
const { set } = Ember;

export default DeviseAuthenticator.extend({
  authenticate: function(registration) {
    const { tokenAttributeName, identificationAttributeName } = this.getProperties('tokenAttributeName', 'identificationAttributeName');
    const data = {};

    return registration.save().then(function(response) {
      set(data, tokenAttributeName, response.get('authToken'));
      set(data, identificationAttributeName, response.get('email'));
      set(data, 'registration', response.toJSON());
      return data;
    });
  }
});
```

and trigger this authenticator in the submit action on our registration form:

```
//app/controllers/registration.js

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  session: Ember.inject.service('session'),
  actions: {
    submit: function() {
      this.get('session')
          .authenticate('authenticator:registration', this.get('model'));
    }
  }
}
```

Our registration form is bound to a registration model object which looks like this:

```
//app/models/registration.js

export default DS.Model.extend(SiteModelMixin, {
  email : DS.attr("string"),
  password : DS.attr("string"),
  authToken : DS.attr("string")
});
```

Comment: this is the route i went too. now i'm trying to migrate to ember-simple-auth 1.0 and session no longer has a setup() method. any ideas?

Comment: Under ember-simple-auth 1.0 we moved the above function into a custom authenticator. I'll post the code in a separate answer as it won't fit in the comment reply.

Answer (score 1):

Marcoow's answer should work for most cases, but in my case the sign up response includes a full authentication session as well as all data for the newly created user(i.e. sign in and sign up responses are identical). Doing a sign in request using the same credentials from the form is a little less than ideal in this case b/c there's an extra network request(which could potentially fail due to spotty network conditions, etc...).

In my case the the responses include an authentication token, so I just provide an object to my custom authenticator which checks for an `authentication_token` in the received data and if so assumes the data is a valid user session(could do some more rigorous validation of the session data if needed) and resolve the promise using the received data resulting in the user session being authenticated with Ember Simple Auth in the Session Service.

If there's no authentication_token, I attempt a sign in using `email` and `password` properties in the data object received by the Authenticator's `authenticate()` call and resolve or reject with the result of the sign in attempt.

Comment: I would love to see some code showing how this is done. I am new to Ember and currently trying to solve this exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and i could not get the session/username/password from 'this' or 'self'. so what i did is:

```
App.session = this.get('session');
App.credentials = {
     identification: data.username,
     password: data.password
};
```

And then i used them in the promise (with default authenticator):

```
user.save().then(function() {
     App.session.authenticate('ember-simple-auth:authenticators:oauth2', App.credentials);
}, function(err) {
     console.log('error ..')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to use another network request, as my API returns the token with the registration response, so I started down the route Drew Nichols had, but didn't like creating a separate model. In the end I found that you can simply extend the model's `handleResponse()` hook in the adapter. Then you only need a simple authenticator that will return the input data (and therefore run that data through the authentication process to add it to the session).

This is all in Ember 2.7.

Here's the `User` model's adapter:

```
// app/adapters/user.js

export default ApplicationAdapter.extend({
  session: Ember.inject.service(),

  handleResponse(status, headers, payload, requestData) {
    if (this.isSuccess(status, headers, payload) && requestData.method === 'POST') {
      this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:registration', payload).catch((reason) => {
        console.error( 'User Adapter Error:', reason );
      });
    }

    this._super(...arguments);
  },
});
```

And the `Registration` Authenticator that's being called above:

```
// app/authenticators/registration.js

export default Base.extend({
  authenticate(response) {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve) => {
      Ember.run.join(null, resolve, response);
    });
  },
});
```

Then to call in the controller (or wherever), you can simply do a regular `save()`:

```
this.get('model').save()
```